# I'm trying to make a 3d model with a texture paint on it. For some reason when I go to rendering/shading some of the textures/colors are gone

Tags: modeling, rendering, uv, color

This is pretty much my first character i've modeled. I painted some texture on it (basically just made the horns black. So for some reason the black color on the horns are gone and instead are now white. What might be the reason for this?[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please show your Shader Editor in Object mode? You're showing it in World mode, are you sure that you want to plug this Image Texture into the Background node? Also maybe share your file so that we can test the painting? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find the shader editor anywhere (I'm bit new to this program) But I can surely share the file! here it is

Comment: You need to share the link   ;)   make sure that you've packed the images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) before saving